# CMake: How to create one object from several source files?

Tags: c, cmake

To build some C library using CMake, I need to build *one* object from several C source files (when building a static library). When using `add_library`, CMake will create an object for *each* source file. (This fails in this case, because the `*.c` files are including other `*.c` files that cannot be build individually as an object, because some definitions would be missing.)

In Make this would look like this

```
file.o: file_part1.c file_part2.c
```

Is there some way to force `add_library` to only build one object from all the C files?

Comment: A static library is nothing more than an archive of object files, there's no linking stage so there can't be any errors due to missing symbols. And rearely, if ever, should you include source files into other source files. If you do that there's something wrong with your project setup.

Comment: As for your "solution", no it's not possible to create a single object file from multiple source file. An object file represents a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), which is the result of building a single source file with all included headers. The standard way to "combine" object files is through static libraries.

Comment: > A static library is nothing more than an archive of object files, there's no linking stage so there can't be any errors due to missing symbols.


The error is before the linking, because some of the used types are not defined.


> And rearely, if ever, should you include source files into other source files. If you do that there's something wrong with your project setup.


This is unfortunately not my choice, it is what is done in the library I want to use. (They use it as some form of monomorphization to reduce code redundancy.)

Comment: Are you talking about ".lib" or ".a" static library files or about ".obj" or ".o" files. If it is the former, we can help you, if it is the latter, you're doing it all wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what do you have and what do you want to achive? `This fails in this case, because the '*.c' files are including other '*.c' files that cannot be build individually as an object` - When call `add_library`, specify only files which are **intended** to be built and omit files which shouldn't be built separately.

Comment: `When call add_library, specify only files which are intended to be built and omit files which shouldn't be built separately.` Yes, this is what I did in the end to solve my problem. I analyzed the include graph and only included the top level files that depend on the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you will always have one object per compilation unit, so the solution is to make sure that only the top-level files in the include graph are used in `add_library`. Then they are the only files to be compiled to objects and linked to a library. CMake can hopefully figure out the dependencies on the included files by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it answers your question, but one usually use the following CMake code snippet to collect files and build a library:

```
# Collect files
# 
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_C ${YOUR_PROJECT_SRC_DIR}/ *.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_H ${YOUR_PROJECT_HEADER_DIR}/ *.h)

# Add library target with its dependencies
#
add_library(YOUR_LIB_NAME ${SOURCE_C} ${SOURCE_H})
```

This is not the best practice because if you add a file the generated Makefile will not detect that and you have to rerun cmake to take it into account.

Comment: This will unfortunately not work, because it compiles the `*.c` files that can only be included to objects, which fails.